# FullCalendar: how to display events in fullcalendar through ajax response

Tags: javascript, jquery, ajax, fullcalendar, jquery-events

I am working in full calendar. Now I need to show up all the events from the database through the ajax call. Till now, I have taken the events from database through JSON.
My JSON output is as follows after the `var_dump`:

```
array (size=3)
  0 => 
    array (size=7)
      'title' => string 'hi' (length=2)
      'id' => int 1
      'start' => string '2016-05-30 00:00:00.000' (length=23)
      'rendering' => string 'background' (length=10)
      'backgroundColor' => string '#ff9999' (length=7)
      'className' => string 'event-full' (length=10)
      'textColor' => string 'white' (length=5)
  1 => 
    array (size=7)
      'title' => string 'vibrator' (length=8)
      'id' => int 3
      'start' => string '2016-05-26 00:00:00.000' (length=23)
      'rendering' => string 'background' (length=10)
      'backgroundColor' => string '#ff9999' (length=7)
      'className' => string 'event-full' (length=10)
      'textColor' => string 'white' (length=5)
  2 => 
    array (size=7)
      'title' => string 'vibrator' (length=8)
      'id' => int 8
      'start' => string '2016-05-26 00:00:00.000' (length=23)
      'rendering' => string 'background' (length=10)
      'backgroundColor' => string '#ff9999' (length=7)
      'className' => string 'event-full' (length=10)
      'textColor' => string 'white' (length=5)
```

and my script through my ajax is as follows:-

```
 events: function(start, end, timezone, callback)
{    
$.ajax({
        url: "calendar/show_events",
        type: 'POST', // Send post data
        data: 'type=fetch_events',
        async: true,
        
        success: function(s){
           
             dynamic_events =s;
                       alert(dynamic_events);
             // $('#calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', JSON.parse(dynamic_events));
              
              var dynamic_events = [];
                $(doc).find('event').each(function() {
                    events.push({
                        title: $(this).attr('title'),
                        start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                    });
                });
                callback(events);
            
              }
    });    
}
```

What is the error in my code.? I want to learn now.
Can anyone help me and save my day?
I am in need to display all the events in the `FullCalendar`.

Comment: What is the error you get?

Comment: @Eyal Abir, Uncaught ReferenceError: doc is not defined

Comment: Uptil my alert(dynamic_events); I am getting the response but i donot know how to make as events in fullcalendar

Comment: You are misusing the variables in the success function. doc is really not defined. you probably meant to go over the `s` variable.

Comment: Ok If so , how should i go over the 's' variable. Somehow i want to show the events in fullcalendar this way..

Comment: I corrected your mistakes but didn't check the parsing. you need to verify that it is being built correctly

Answer (score -1):

Change your ajax code to that

```
$.ajax({
    url: "calendar/show_events",
    type: 'POST', // Send post data
    data: 'type=fetch_events',
    async: true,

    success: function(s){

          var dynamic_events = [];
            $(s).find('event').each(function() {
                dynamic_events.push({
                    title: $(this).attr('title'),
                    start: $(this).attr('start') // will be parsed
                });
            });
            callback(dynamic_events);

          }
});
```

Comment: But I got the error like this, when i do like this..Uncaught Error: Syntax error, unrecognized expression: [{"title":"hi","id":1,"start":"2016-05-30 00:00:00.000","rendering":"background","backgroundColor":"#ff9999","className":"event-full","textColor":"white"},{"title":"vibrator","id":3,"start":"2016-05-26 00:00:00.000","rendering":"background","backgroundColor":"#ff9999","className":"event-full","textColor":"white"},{"title":"vibrator","id":8,"start":"2016-05-26 00:00:00.000","rendering":"background","backgroundColor":"#ff9999","className":"event-full","textColor":"white"}}]

Comment: When does it happen? This string has 2 problems anyway, there is an extra `}` before the end and for some reason there is a speacial character that probably make you problems. I copy pasted it to [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/fdj1cysy/) take a look