# Fullcalendar: Bootstrap Modal Box not displaying elements correctly

Tags: javascript, datepicker, fullcalendar, bootstrap-modal

A Full calendar Script in one of my project in which i added a Bootstrap modal. I am making it to popup on submit of a Button in my page.But the elements inside the modal are not visible clearly. where am i making the mistake?. 
I do have a datepicker in my code, but it is also not displayed with proper 'prev','next' buttons. I have added a sample pic too.Kindly help me..
The following is my code:-

```
<div class="modal fade in" id="modal_calendar" tabindex="-1" role="dialog" aria-hidden="false" style="display: block;">
<div class="modal-dialog">
<div class="modal-content">
<div class="modal-header">
  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal" aria-label="Close"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span></button>
     <h4 class="modal-title">Add Event </h4>
</div>
      <div class="modal-body">
         <form id="event_frm" class="form-horizontal">

<div class="form-group">
   <div class="form-group "><label class="control-label col-sm-3 " for="calendar_eventsubject">calendar_eventsubject</label><div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="calendar_eventsubject" value="" id="calendar_eventsubject" placeholder="calendar_eventsubject" data-validation-required-message="Enter the calendar_eventsubject" class="form-control" required="">
</div></div>  </div>
  <div class="form-group">
  <div class="form-group "><label class="control-label col-sm-3 " for="calendar_eventbody">calendar_eventbody</label><div class="col-sm-8"><textarea name="calendar_eventbody" cols="40" rows="3" id="calendar_eventbody" placeholder="calendar_eventbody" data-validation-required-message="Enter the calendar_eventbody" class="form-control" required=""></textarea>
</div></div>
       </div>
      <div class="row">
      <div class="form-group "><label class="control-label col-sm-3 " for="lbl_disp_code">common_date</label><div class="col-sm-8"><input type="text" name="lbl_disp_code" value="" id="lbl_disp_code" placeholder="common_date" data-validation-required-message="Enter the common_date" class="mts_date form-control" data-format="DD-MM-YYYY" data-single-date-picker="true" data-show-dropdowns="true" required="">
</div></div>      <div class="control-label col-sm-3">
    <label for="start_date">Start Date</label>
    </div>
    <div class="col-sm-7">
    <input type="text" class="form-control hasDatepicker" id="event_start_date" placeholder="Start Date">
    </div>

  </div>
        </form>
      </div>
      <div class="modal-footer">
        <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
              <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" id="save_event">Save changes</button>
       </div>
      </div><!-- /.modal-content -->
   </div><!-- /.modal-dialog -->
 </div>

    <script>
    $(document).ready(function() {

        $('#calendar').fullCalendar({ 
            customButtons: {
                EventButton: {
                    text:'Add Event',
                    click:function(event, jsEvent, view){
                        $('#modal_calendar').modal('show');
                    }
                }
            },

            utc: true, 
            header: { 
                left: 'prev,next today EventButton', 
                center: 'title', 
                right: 'month,agendaWeek,agendaDay' 
            },   

            editable: true, 
            droppable: true, 
        });

        $('#event_start_date').datepicker();
        $('#save_event').click(function() {
            var subject =$('#calendar_eventsubject').val();
            var body =$('#calendar_eventbody').val();
            var start_date = $('#event_start_date').val();
            if($('#calendar_event_subject').val() =='') {
                alert('subject required'); return false;
            } else {
                $("#modal_calendar").modal('hide');
            }

            if($('#calendar_event_body').val() == '') {
                alert('Body required'); return false;
            } else {
                $("#modal_calendar").modal('hide');
            }

            if($('#event_start_date').val() == '') {
                alert('Start Date required'); return false;
            } else {
                $("#modal_calendar").modal('hide');
            }

            $.ajax({
                cache: false,
                type: "POST",
                url:"calendar/save_event",
                data :  {'subject' : subject,'body' : body,'start_date' : start_date},
                dataType: 'json',
                success: function(result){
                    if (result!=null){
                    }
                }
            });
        });
    });
    </script>
    <style>
    .datepicker
    {
        z-index:1151 !important;}

    </style>
```

From this my output is like this:-

[image: Calendar Image]

Comment: Indentation goes a long way. You are missing a closing div and you have a `<form>` tag below `modal-body` thar you never close (and worse you are opening another form inside that form, which is beyond invalid). Please fix this issues and, if your main issue remains, create a fiddle that replicates the issue. Thanks

Comment: @milz, I actually modified the form details now, but thats only the sample code for the form. Any way my issue is with the elements of the date picker

Comment: Check [this codepen](http://codepen.io/milz/pen/XKWxgY) where the datepicker is working. You need to add the full code as you have it, because your HTML doesn't have a calendar and you modal doesn't have a datepicker. So we can't replicate your exact issue. Please add all the relevant code (providing a fiddle would be a plus). Thanks!

Comment: https://jsfiddle.net/Keynes105/qskortur/ This is my fiddle, but now i am not getting the date picker though

Comment: You need to add the libraries on the "External Resources" (left panel). I've added a few and updated [the fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/qskortur/1/), but you're using a `daterangepicker()` and a `datepicker()` (which I assumed it was jquery-ui). You now need to add the external resource of the daterangepicker and it should work.

Comment: Ok milz, I have got this error, Cannot read property 'hasTime' of undefined. I don know why this error has come?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/113381/discussion-between-keynes-and-milz).